# Is it correct and natural to say/write: "He was struck by a satellite."?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, passive-voice

I'm in the middle of watching the TV series "Northern Exposure." In one of the episodes, one person died because of an accident.

Can I say/write: **"He was struck by a satellite."**

Is it correct to use the verb "strike" here? The person was hit by the satellite, so I wondered if the verb "strike" suited here.

Comment: What is it about the definition of "strike" that makes you think it would not be applicable here?

Comment: @DJClayworth Maybe OP wasn't sure whether the word can be used when not referring to lightning (which it can)?

Comment: @DJClayworth According to one of the definitions of the word "strike" [(of a disaster, disease, or other unwelcome phenomenon) occur suddenly and have harmful or damaging effects on.) "a major earthquake struck the island"], it fits perfectly. Still, I'm not a native English speaker, so I need more examples and confirmations to make sure I can use some verbs in a specific context. That's why I asked the question. I guess, I was looking for reassurance.

Comment: Was the person floating in space?

Comment: What type of satellite was it? Was it a space satellite? Was it a meteorite maybe? Did it fall from the sky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct usage of the word “strike.” One meaning of strike is “one thing hits another thing” - and that is exactly what happened here.

Comment: Correct? I suppose. But it also sounds a bit peculiar. Usually the expression *to be struck by an X* is used to describe pedestrians in situations where *X* is some vehicle. (Yes, *X* can also be “bolt of lightning.”) I’d say that *hit* would be more idiomatic. Of course, in the spirit of *Northern Exposure*, one might wish to adopt its quirky tone, and if so, then maybe *struck* is the way to go.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - You can be struck by a bullet, a train, a rock, a piece of ice from a plane's toilet, a fragment of a burst flywheel, among other things. I see no oddity in the use of that verb.

Comment: Yeah, @MichaelHarvey, maybe it’s a feature of my dialect. I can’t put my thumb on it. But at least one other user upvoted it. I dunno.

Comment: Not to mention an idea or thought.

Comment: Not to mention [dumb.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+struck+dumb%22) Or [thirteen.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22struck+thirteen%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I thought I'd experienced most of what life has to offer, but I've never been struck thirteen yet. It sounds sort of uncomfortable.